# Could we use the word pop-culture books to describe bestsellers

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I see some of the best-sellers book. Some of them are like pseudo-scientific. 
But they are very popular. 
How could we describe a book or content like this ? 
Is pop-culture book a correct word ? The book/content that I want to describe is like
gives lot of details about something and is very famous/best-seller kind of stuff 
But it certainly is not scientific/emperical

Comment: Why not use 'pseudo-science books'? Pop-culture is something else. Also, not all best-sellers are pseudo-science or pop-culture. Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: https://devdutt.com/books/ Consider the book on this website <br> There is no psychological research backing it.  Or consider some spiritual books. <br> Which seems to talk in a way that appears scientific but is not. Some people hold a high status of them in their minds... Yeah I can use `pseudo-science` that sounds perfect. But if I say that to the person he will get offended. So I was looking for a lighter word. I find many of the bestsellers motivational/inspirational books pseudo-scientific

Answer (score 1):

"Pop-culture" is a very broad term. It is not a genre, and it is not exclusive to the medium of books. If something is part of '*popular culture*' it simply means that it has an audience and is likely to be enjoyed by, or at least known to, a wide audience of ordinary people. Media which makes reference to other media (for example, a book that mentions the titles of real songs or movies) is often said to contain "pop-culture references".

I don't think you mean to say that these books *contain* pop-culture. What I think you are trying to say is that "**pseudo-science has found its way into popular culture**". Your evidence for this statement is that many books on pseudo-science have become best-sellers (ie. they have become popular).

Comment: Yeah You have put it exactly when you said `pseudo-science has found its way into popular culture` So when I say pop-culture the domain covers more than books. It could be anything right ? Is there a better word to express this than `pseudo-science`

Comment: @pensee Be careful how you use "pop culture", because it is very hard to define. A book or song shouldn't be described as "pop culture"... it becomes *part* of pop culture when it proves popular. As for 'pseudo-science'... there isn't really a better term for it. Although it is broad - it could include unproved medical advice, or conspiracy theories. You could be more specific and say "*pseudo-scientific medical books*" or "*pseudo-scientific self-help books*"?

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. Also on the similar lines. I have noticed many times people say things like `Eating an apple in morning has the same effect as coffee`  I am sure you must have heard of many such statements which a group of community/people believes in. Like many supersitious things people believe in...What do you think will be a correct term for that ? Could we call that pseudoscience ? or I guess there must be a better word for that

Comment: @pensee "Pseudo-science" generally goes a little bit beyond saying things that are patently untrue. Like homeopathy, for example. It doesn't just say that x cures y, it has some convoluted explanation for why it works, one that is contrary to science. "Eating an apple has the same effect as coffee" is what we might call *an urban myth*, or *an old wives' tale* - snippets of nonsense that are passed along verbally without any support to the statement.